# A Language With These Traits

Tags: programming-languages

I'm looking for a programming language that has the following features:

1. First-class functions and anonymous functions/code blocks
2. Mixins
3. Standard OO (at least inheritance and some encapsulation, probably classes over prototypes)
4. Fast to write, but preferably more through shorter keywords/operators than by making up a lot of it's own new concepts/sugar (obviously there's some subjectivity here, so I'm leaving it open-ended).

And has strong library support for:

1. The web (including HTTP, HTML templating, databases, and asset handling)
2. Dependency injection
3. Unit testing

It should also be able to do matrix manipulation better than abysmally, whether as part of the language or through libraries.

I don't want to start any open-ended, philosophical debates :) I'm just looking for some languages that fit the above bill.

Edit: I know Ruby's close but I'm looking for something with a little less sugar. Also, from what I understand about symbols they're basically rampant global state, which isn't great.

Comment: Python with Spring.py and scipy/numpy

Comment: Inappropriate question. But you are definitely talking about ruby

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**python:**

> First-class functions and anonymous functions/code blocks

check! (lambda for anonymous function calls)

> Mixins

You can inherit from multiple classes in python

> Standard OO (at least inheritance and some encapsulation, probably classes over prototypes)

check!

> Fast to write, but preferably more through shorter keywords/operators than by making up a lot of it's own new concepts/sugar (obviously there's some subjectivity here, so I'm leaving it open-ended).

python is fast to write and easy to read. The syntax is pretty intuitive I think.

> The web (including HTTP, HTML templating, databases, and asset handling)

http://wiki.python.org/moin/WebFrameworks

> Dependency injection

python might lag behind a little bit here. There is no equivalent of Spring for python to my knowledge, but the language does provide the ability to do so. See http://wiki.python.org/moin/DependencyInjectionPattern

> Unit testing

check! http://docs.python.org/library/unittest.html

> It should also be able to do matrix manipulation better than abysmally, whether as part of the language or through libraries.

checkout numpy for starter: [Link](https://numpy.org/). I think there are better solutions out there as well.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how good matrix manipulation is (it [does have it](http://corelib.rubyonrails.org/classes/Matrix.html)), but Ruby (with Ruby on Rails for web framework) seems to fit your description